# mdadm RAID comes up inactive each reboot

Tags: mdadm

I have a mdadm software RAID6 that comes up inactive upon each reboot. All its disk are present but shown as spares. How do I make it start operational (active)?

This is it's state after reboot:

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sdg[2](S) sdf[1](S) sde[3](S) sdc[5](S) sdb[0](S) sda[4](S)
      xxxxxx blocks
unused devices: <none>
```

again here

```
sudo  mdadm --detail --scan           
INACTIVE-ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=0.90 UUID=xxx
```

it is not possible just to assemble it, even with --force

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sdg is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdf is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sde is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdc is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdb is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sda is busy - skipping

sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --force --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sdg is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdf is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sde is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdc is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdb is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sda is busy - skipping
```

But it can be manually assembled after I stop it:

```
sudo mdadm --manage --stop /dev/md0
mdadm: stopped /dev/md0
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 6 drives.
sudo  mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=0.90 bitmap=/media/intent.bin UUID=xxx
```

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

mdadm - v4.1-rc1 - 2018-03-22

What I have noticed is that

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sd[abcefg]
```

shows /dev/sde missing in the list below. (Only /dev/sde missing in that table for all disks/devices)

```
      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     3       8      112        3      active sync

   0     0       8       48        0      active sync   /dev/sdd
   1     1       8        0        1      active sync   /dev/sda
   2     2       8       16        2      active sync   /dev/sdb
   3     3       8      112        3      active sync
   4     4       8       32        4      active sync   /dev/sdc
   5     5       8       80        5      active sync   /dev/sdf
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was the `bitmap=/media/intent.bin` statement in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`
After I have just letft `ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=xxx` there, the array started active after the reboot.
(However now I have a problem that it doesn't use the external bitmap as it should.)

Comment: Is `/media/intent.bin` available at the time the system tries to start the array?

Comment: Thanks @roaima this is exactly what happened. I have opened another question about that issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083596/what-happened-with-the-mdadm-doesnt-start-array-with-external-bitmap-bug

Comment: Oh ok. Please remember to accept your own answer here (when you can).